# create a directory at remote server with sftp laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sftp, file-permissions, flysystem

I am trying to create a new directory at remote server and set permission to the directory.

```
$remote_path = $clientName . '/' . $fileNameToStore;
Storage::disk('sftp')->makeDirectory($clientName, 'public');                    
$ftp = Storage::disk('sftp')->put($remote_path, fopen($uploadedFile, 'r+'), 'public');
```

However it doesn't seem to work.

The below line creates the directory itself but the dir. permission is always `744`.

How can I change the permission to directory also, as I have done it to the file with `public`?